# Facebook python sdk uses marketing api or graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

I have been using **facebook python SDK** for nearly 6 months for building a product.

I have dev access for the marketing api.
It frequently errors out saying Rate limit has exceeded. But when i check marketing api dashboard it says not enough data available.

So Im really confused whether SDK uses marketing API or graph API.

Can anybody explain me the usage.

Any info will be much appreciated.

Comment: What particular API is involved, depends much more on what you are doing, than what specific SDK you are using. So what are you actually confused about here - you should know what your “product” is and does to begin with …?

Comment: @cbroe the product mainly creates ad campaigns. And fetch ad insights. But im more worried about the creation process

Comment: _“mainly creates ad campaigns. And fetch ad insights”_ - both of those are part of Marketing API.

Comment: Thanks @cbroe. That cleared my one confusion. The reason I doubted this in the first place is, i run into rate limit everyday, but in the marketing api dashboard it never shows any data. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: why tag the php sdk, when you are actually using the python sdk?