# Facebook graph API vs marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can someone explain me the difference between facebook's graph API and marketing API.

Also which one should be used for which requests.

I have been using facebook python SDK to create ads. But I run into rate limits every now and then. But in my marketing API dashboard I dont see any data.

Any info will be very much appreciated

Comment: You asked this already an hour ago, no need for a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51479955/1427878

Comment: In this question i want to know the general difference between both and their use cases. the other question is about python sdk.

Comment: why use facebook-fql as tag? fql is gone since many years. also, there is no javascript sdk code, or php sdk code. not sure why you are using all those tags? you only mention the python sdk.

Comment: _“In this question i want to know the general difference between both and their use cases.”_ - then you should start by reading their respective documentation. _“Also which one should be used for which requests.”_ - you are trying to saddle the horse from the wrong end here. What API you need to use, depends on what functionality you want to implement. They are not interchangeable in that you could decide to use either one to implement functionality X. That X dictates what API you need to use to begin with.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this question here is because I read the documentation and didn't understand it. I'm well aware of the documentation. Facebook API documentation interchangeably uses both in examples. So I wanted to ask people who have actually used these services and have some knowledge about these services for recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

The Graph API is named after the idea of a "social graph" — a representation of the information on Facebook. It's composed of:

nodes — basically individual objects, such as a User, a Photo, a Page, or a Comment
edges — connections between a collection of objects and a single object, such as Photos on a Page or Comments on a Photo
fields — data about an object, such as a User's birthday, or a Page's name
Typically you use nodes to get data about a specific object, use edges to get collections of objects on a single object, and use fields to get data about a single object or each object in a collection.

You can get more information from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/explorer/

the Marketing APIs, access, versioning and more. The main use cases for the Marketing API are ads insights, audience management, and ads management and you can find more about it from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/using-the-api

Answer (score 0):

Marketing api is just another service provided by facebook Graph Api. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/