# Which Facebook API calls count against the Marketing API rate limit?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/best-practices/#adsoverview states that

> Marketing API has it is own rate limiting logic and is excluded from all the graph api rate limitations. So if you make a Marketing API call, it won't be calculated into the Graph API throttling.

But it's not clear from the documentation what calls count as part of the marketing API.

- E.g. [this](http://%20https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api) Marketing API documentation uses the URL https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/... which has 'Graph' in
- Ad Insights are discussed in the Marketing API docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api), but...
- Making calls as described in those docs, e.g. to

  https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/act_.../insights

  does *not* seem to increase the #Marketing API calls as listed in the Facebook app used to access the Marketing API.

I'd be grateful for any explanation of these inconsistent facts. Please note that I have read

[Facebook graph API vs marketing api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480873/facebook-graph-api-vs-marketing-api)

and this is not a duplicate of that q., which doesn't discuss rate limiting at all.

Comment: As far as I can see, the whole Marketing API uses `graph.facebook.com`. _“But it's not clear from the documentation what calls count as part of the marketing API”_ - those described in the Marketing API part of the documentation, presumably …

Comment: Except that many of those calls _don't_ increase the #Marketing API calls counted internally in the platform...